# JQuery CheckBoxes Price addition and deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      var priceTotal = 0;
      $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          priceTotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      });
      $('#total').html(priceTotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator">
      <input type="checkbox" />$29<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" />$39<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" />$49<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" />$59<br/>
    </div>
<div class="total"><span>$0</span></div>
```

**Task**: Based on the checkboxes Prices should be added in total class.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      var priceTotal = 0;
      $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          priceTotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      });
      $('#total').html(priceTotal);
  });
});
```

I want when picking up the numerical values from checkboxes the currency sign should be stripped and later added.

**Reason**: It will be used finally in Sambhal, setting where the currency may not be a dollar in all the cases.

The best policy will be to get the currency in some data-set and then transfer it to the JQuery.

Please help me to accomplish this.

I do not want to use value inside input.

can we use this kind of HTML:

```
<div class="inputbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
  <label for="option1">Services</label><span class="license_price bold">€29</span>
</div>
```

When checkbox ticked we can get the price of that span through class? That's the demand actually.

Comment: value of the checkbox returns `on` or `off`. THe prices you set as text have nothing to do with the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Calculate Total in one  variable in each loop and with interger parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the html the value corresponding to the checkbox could be retrieved with `.nextSibling.textContent` and you need to change the total selector to `.total` as you have it as a class and not id:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var originalPrice = +$('.total').html();
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var priceTotal = originalPrice;
    $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
      priceTotal += parseInt($(this).siblings('.license_price.bold').html().replace("€", ''), 10);
    });
    $('.total').html(priceTotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator">
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
    <label for="option1">Services1</label><span class="license_price bold"> €29</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
    <label for="option2">Services2</label><span class="license_price bold"> €39</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
    <label for="option3">Services3</label><span class="license_price bold"> €49</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inputbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="option4">
    <label for="option4">Services4</label><span class="license_price bold"> €59</span>
  </div>
</div>
<span>$<span class="total">56</span></span>
```

Comment: Sir, In case of my updated code will it work? Input→label→span? Not next sibling. span is 2nd to next sibling?

Comment: @wocommerce115 yes kind sir it most definitely would!  you can check my updated code which is on similar lines

Comment: Perfect. Answer accepted. You are a genius I have accepted the answer

Comment: waht if this was → `<span>$<span class="total">$89</span></span>` extra amount should be added/deleted to this.

Comment: you could add the symbol directly in the code `$('.total').html('$' + priceTotal);` or maintain a variable to hold the value: `const currency = "$";`

Comment: Thanks. You are nice.

Comment: You are slightly missing the point. One value si already there and then checkbox prices are to be added/deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I am a novice can you update the actual code sir?

Comment: you can declare a variable called original price and assign it each time checkbox is clicked;

Comment: how to add that in final price after check box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201197/discussion-between-shrys-and-wocommerce115).

Answer (score 2):

There are severel errors:

You didn't have set any values to your inputs. So the value they return is just `on` or `off`.

Set them directly as attribute.

Then you select the output wrong. Your html total has a class, you select a id. Plus you set the html wrong.

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o260skn9/

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problem:

1 there is no value property on your input.

2 you are using `$('#total')` and not `$('.total')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      var priceTotal = 0;
      $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          priceTotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      });
      $('.total').html(priceTotal);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      var priceTotal = 0;
      $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          priceTotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      });
      $('.total').html(priceTotal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator">
      <input type="checkbox" value="29" />$29<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="39" />$39<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="49" />$49<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="59" />$59<br/>
    </div>
<div class="total"><span>$0</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i have fixed your code..
the best way is if you value take from html that's not a good way.
the better is you should use value attribute.
it's just a suggestion
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      var priceTotal = 0;
      $("#calculator input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
          priceTotal += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      });
      $('#total').html(priceTotal);
  });
       

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator">
      <input type="checkbox" value="29" />$29<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="39" />$39<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="49" />$49<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="59" />$59<br/>
    </div>
<div class="total">$<span id="total">0</span></div>
```